# modifying an application using wicket

Tags: java, wicket

I'm trying to modify an application using wicket, what I'am trying to do is to create a new webpage(html) and a .java file.

I've added the following line in the application:

```
mountPage("/statistics.html", statistics.class);
```

in hopes of redirecting to that page when a label is clicked:

```
setResponsePage(statistics.html, itemSearch.getAsQueryString());
```

here's what I get though:

```
annot access statistics
    [javac]                 setResponsePage(statistics.html, itemSearch.getAsQueryString());
```

heres the statistics.html file:
hello

it's in the same directory as the other files

I'm sorry if I'm unable to make things clearer, please let me know if you need any additional info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such method in Wicket API: `setResponsePage(statistics.html, itemSearch.getAsQueryString());`.
The actual method is: `setResponsePage(Class, PageParameters)`.
I.e. you have to use it like: `setResponsePage(statistics.class, parameters);`

Comment: that is the methid I'm using to retrieve the parameters, removing that method will yield nothing :(
looking at the actual method, how can I point to my own html/java files in the setResponsePage?  using the project classes work, how can I create my own class file? a work around would be fine
thank you.

Comment: `setResponsePage(statistics.class)` points to your compiled Java. Try it! First try without the parameters/query string, once it works fine then add the PageParameters.